# Ranking and Unranking binary Permutation with distance criteria

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I want to rank and unrank binary permutations with a distance criteria.

Example:

`maxDistance := 2`

Valid binary permutations consisting the elements `0011` are following:

`0101` -> Rank 0

`1010` -> Rank 1

`0110` -> invalid because the first index of `0` is 0 but the second occurence of `0` has index 3. `3-0 > maxDistance`

`0011` -> invalid because the first occurence of `1` is at index 2 but the distance is 3.

`distance` is calculated, via equal elements index, of two adjecent equal elements doesnt differ more than `abs(distance)`, but for the first occurence of an element the `index+1 == distance`.
The  `maxDistance` applies for `0` and `1`.
There can be unequal occurences of `0,1` in the binary permutation.
`Rank` is the index of the given permutation in an ordered list of valid permutations.

to rank = binary permutation to indexnumber(Rank), maxDistance

to unrank = Rank+occurences `0`+occurences `1`+maxDistance to permutation

```
int calcMaxDistance(BitSet set){
  int max0 =0;
  int max1 =0;
  int lastIndex0 =0;
  int lastIndex1 =0;

  for(int i=0; i < set.size();i++){
    if(set.get(i)){
      if(lastIndex1 ==0 && max1 ==0){
        max1 = i+1;
      }else{
        if(i - lastIndex1 > max1){
          max1 = i - lastIndex1;
        }
      }
      lastIndex1 = i;
    }else{
      // Same structure for max0 like with max1
    }
  }
  return Math.max(max0,max1);
}
```

Has anybody an idea how to construct the algorithm?

Comment: Is `1100` valid or invalid?

Comment: Its invalid, because of the same reason Like ```0011```

Comment: Can you write code to calculate `distance`?  I think I understand it, but I'm not certain.  And I'd like a way to test my idea.

Comment: Also would handling 3+ symbols be interesting?

Comment: I don't have the energy to implement this, but it is the same idea I've described before. Use dynamic programming to create a recursive data structure that you can then walk to rank/unrank.  The state will be position in output, how recently each character was last used, and how many of each character are left.  To this state you attach a count, and next/character, next part of the data.

Comment: Yes more Handling more than 2 symbols would be optimal, but not necessary. Can you describe your Idea in more detail please.

Comment: updated question with ```calcMaxDistance()``` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation.

First, a top-down dynamic programming approach to analyzing the admissible permutations.  If you have symbol counts `n1, n2, ..., nk` then this can take time as bad as `O(n1*n2*...*nk)`.

```
def analyze_distance_perm(symbols, distance):
    s_count = {}
    for s in symbols:
        if s in s_count:
            s_count[s] += 1
        else:
            s_count[s] = 1
    starting_state = []
    for s, count in s_count.items():
        starting_state.append((s, 1, count))

    cache = {}
    def recur (remain, state):
        key = (remain, tuple(state))
        if key not in cache:
            if 0 == remain:
                cache[key] = {"c": 1, "t": None}
                for s, dist, left in state:
                    if distance < dist:
                        cache[key] = None
                        break
            else:
                next_state = []
                for i in range(len(state)):
                    s, dist, left = state[i]
                    if distance < dist:
                        next_state = None
                    elif next_state is not None:
                        next_state.append((s, dist+1, left))
                if next_state is None:
                    cache[key] = None
                else:
                    count = 0
                    transition = {}
                    for i in range(len(next_state)):
                        s, dist, left = next_state[i]
                        if 0 < left:
                            next_state[i] = (s, 1, left-1)
                            result = recur(remain-1, next_state)
                            if result is not None:
                                count += result['c']
                                transition[s] = result
                            next_state[i] = (s, dist, left)
                    if 0 == len(transition):
                        cache[key] = None
                    else:
                        cache[key] = {'c': count, 't': transition}

        return cache[key]
    return recur(len(symbols), starting_state)
```

With this analysis in hand, ranking/unranking is straightforward.  (I chose to call the rank the number of permutations before, so the first one has rank 0.  It is easy to adjust that if you want.)

```
def rank_perm(perm, analysis):
    if 0 == len(perm):
        return 0
    elif analysis is None or perm[0] not in analysis['t']:
        return None
    rank = 0
    for s, subanalysis in analysis['t'].items():
        if s != perm[0]:
            rank += subanalysis['c']
        else:
            subrank = rank_perm(perm[1:], subanalysis)
            if subrank is None:
                return None
            else:
                return rank + subrank

def perm_at_rank(rank, analysis):
    return list(reversed(_perm_at_rank(rank, analysis)))

def _perm_at_rank(rank, analysis):
    if analysis is None or analysis['t'] is None:
        if rank == 0:
            return []
        else:
            return None

    for s, subanalysis in analysis['t'].items():
        if rank < subanalysis['c']:
            subperm = _perm_at_rank(rank, subanalysis)
            if subperm is None:
                return None
            else:
                subperm.append(s)
                return subperm
        else:
            rank -= subanalysis['c']
```

And here is your original example showing it can rank and unrank every permutation correctly.

```
analysis = analyze_distance_perm('0011', 2)
for i in range(analysis['c']):
    perm = perm_at_rank(i, analysis)
    print(i, perm, rank_perm(perm, analysis))
```

And a less trivial example.

```
analysis = analyze_distance_perm('0001122', 4)
for i in range(analysis['c']):
    perm = perm_at_rank(i, analysis)
    print(i, perm, rank_perm(perm, analysis))
```

Comment: looks very nice big thank you, iam still trying  to fully understand it, i will give you an update, but fo now every thing seems to be perfect